# What is msgcat and how to use it

Tags: windows, localization, gettext

Please give me information about how to merge two .po files using msgcat and how to install msgcat.

Comment: How do you know that you need something, but know absolutely nothing about it, or how to obtain it, or even what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded gettext-0.14.4.exe from
http://svn.softwarepublico.gov.br/trac/invesalius/browser/invesalius2/branches/slice_editor/req/gettext-0.14.4.exe?rev=2038

After installing it went to the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" in command prompt.
then used the command ***msgcat "" "" --output-file=""*** I could concatenate the two po files successfully.

Answer (score 7):

`msgcat` is a tool from the GNU `gettext` suite of tools.

> The **msgcat** program concatenates and merges the specified PO files. It
>   finds messages which are common to two or more of the specified PO
>   files. By using the --more-than option, greater commonality may be
>   requested before messages are printed. Conversely, the --less-than
>   option may be used to specify less commonality before messages are
>   printed (i.e. ‘--less-than=2’ will only print the unique messages).
>   Translations, comments and extract comments will be cumulated, except
>   that if --use-first is specified, they will be taken from the first PO
>   file to define them. File positions from all PO files will be
>   cumulated.

Some more documentation about it can be found on *[this page](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/msgcat-Invocation.html)* from the gnu.org site.

You can download a **Windows compiled version** of the executable as part of the **GnuWin32** initiative on [this page](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm).

Comment: Also I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052736/how-can-i-merge-2-pot-files-translation-files

Comment: I installed the package from the link i posted. But after how can I merge the .po files?

Comment: Did you try what is being suggested in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4053017/335418)?

Comment: Did you meant this "msgcat *.pot > all.pot"

Comment: I add the command given in console below.                             
$ msgcat C:\tutorial.po > C:\tutorial.po Now i get "-bash: msgcat: command not found"

Comment: You might have an issue with you PATH env variable. Check [those answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bash+command+not+found) in order to resolve your issue.

Comment: Could you please give a sample command for msgcat or msginit. I cannot understand it from the manual http://www.examplenow.com/msginit/man1#lbAI