# Is it possible to generate a single .pot file from Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python, localization, internationalization, gettext, python-sphinx

I'm undergoing the task of i18n / l10n the documentation of a largish project. The documentation is done with Sphinx, that has off-the shelf [basic support for i18n](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/intl.html).

My problem is similar to that of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4052736/146792): namely the fact a large chunk of the strings for each pot file is the same, and I would like my translators not to re-enter the same translation over and again. **I would rather have a single template file**.

My problem is not really merging the files (that is just a `msgcat *.pot > all.pot` away), but rather the fact that - for the domains to work when building the documentation in a particular language - I have to copy and rename `all.pot` back to the original file names. So my workaroundish way of working is:

1. Generate `fileA.pot`, `fileB.pot`
2. Merge the two into `all.pot`
3. `cp all.pot fileA.pot` + `cp all.pot fileB.pot`

Is there a cleaner way to do the same? [gettext_compact](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/config.html#confval-gettext_compact) brings me only half-way through my goal...

Comment: Have you considered using a Translation Memory (which has unique source/translation key-values)?

Comment: @Shervin - Yes I did, but that would considerably increase the complexity of the architecture without bringing any benefit to the outcome (over my present workaround).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After over 7 months, extensive research and a couple of attempted answers, it seems safe to say that no - at least with the current version 1.1.3 - **it is not possible to generate a single `.pot` file from Sphinx documentation**.

The workaround described in the original question is also the most straightforward for automatically removing duplicate strings when merging the different `.pot` files into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities here:

One is to hack Sphinx to not use domains at all… which I guess you won’t want to do for several reasons.

The other is: since you split by domains, the -M option of [msggrep](http://man.cx/msggrep) looks like it does what you need to do. Otherwise, the -N option can still be used to filter by source file(s).

That is, if the obvious solution doesn't work:

- generate fileA.pot, fileB.pot (also look at [msguniq](http://man.cx/msguniq) here)
- merge them into all.pot and give that to translators
- `for x in file*.pot; do msgmerge -o ${x%t} all-translated.po $x; done`

According to [TFM](http://man.cx/msgmerge), msgmerge only takes the (supposedly newer) translations from its first argument (the translated po file) that match the up-to-date source locations of the second argument (po file with old translations, or pot file = template with only empty msgstrings).

Comment: I'm not sure I got what the technical advantage of this solution is, over my present hack, could you please clarify?

Comment: I understood your present hack to have all strings in the eventual fileA.pot and fileB.pot files and thought you wanted to clean them up. If that’s not the case I fear I did not understand your problem correctly, can you clear up how we can help?

Comment: The title of the question says it all already. :) Also, your answer seems to replicate - in a longer way - what the solution described in the question already does (try for yourself, the resulting .pot is already clean and does not need any more mangling)... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `conf.py` :

```
gettext_compact = "docs"
```